# Error while registering in the application using firebase and flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

im making an blog application using flutter and firebase but i dont know whats wrong in my code and im not able to register it and give me this error.

> [+21177 ms] I/zygote64(18799): Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
>   [  +73 ms] I/zygote64(18799): After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
>   [   +1 ms] I/zygote64(18799): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
>   [+2066 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [  +11 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [ +134 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [  +12 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +3 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [  +31 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +3 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [ +122 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +5 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [ +242 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +3 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +2 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
>   [   +1 ms] W/IInputConnectionWrapper(18799): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
>   [+10343 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799): Failed to handle method call
>   [   +3 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:218)
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.getAuth(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:80)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:94)
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:329)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   [   +2 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
>   [   +1 ms] E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(18799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
>   [  +10 ms] I/flutter (18799): Error: PlatformException(error, FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. , null)
>   [+32829 ms] I/zygote64(18799): Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
>   [   +2 ms] I/zygote64(18799): After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=44KB
>   [   +1 ms] I/zygote64(18799): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

here is the code link [blog](https://github.com/sadsouler/blog)

Comment: Please post the relevant code in this question.

Comment: I have added code at the last of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned the link you provided, Firebase integration is not done in the correct way. I run your project and done the corrections.
If you are interested you can get the [code here](https://github.com/seddiqsorush/firebase_auth), but I recommend to go through this link
 [Firebase Authentication with Flutter](https://medium.com/@abeythilakeudara3/firebase-authentication-with-flutter-d403bf39a029?) and try to do by your own, make sure you add all dependencies and also add `google-services.json` at `Your_Project/android/app`, Also make sure to run `flutter clean` in the root directory of your project

Comment: sure tell me where are my mistake so that i can lean it from it

Comment: I edited the question and added the link

Comment: I tried to access the code but not working 404 not found

Comment: I made changes and upload it again, try now, please make sure you update `google-services.json` and put yours before running the project

Comment: thank you i will try it

Comment: i tried but this time it gave me this error `Error: PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid
API key. ], null)`

Comment: Delete `google-services.json` and download `google-services` file from your Firebase project and paste it in the same place, this will solve the issue

Comment: i did that but still the same error

Comment: I tested the app, it's working perfectly, I just delete my own `api_key`

Comment: i will re-write again

Comment: thank you man for helping me out it's working properly now I'm really grateful for helping me out

Comment: Great, glad to hear that

Comment: I have solved all the  problem but in the end, there is one thing I'm not getting with is with receiving image from firebase it's telling `'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
` i have updated my git repo